# My Bukkit plugin command throws an exception

Tags: java, plugins, yaml, minecraft

My Bukkit plugin command always throws an exception when I run it.

When I type my command: `/config set` (it should save info to file/config), I get this error in chat:

> An internal error occurred while attemping to perform this command.

Why does this happen?

Console Log:

```
[13:23:24 INFO]: whispereq issued server command: /config set
[13:23:24 ERROR]: null
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'config' in plugin registyPlayer v1.0
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:175) ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:683) ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:952) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:814) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:28) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.PacketPlayInChat.handle(PacketPlayInChat.java:47) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:146) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.ServerConnection.c(SourceFile:134) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:655) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.DedicatedServer.u(DedicatedServer.java:250) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:545) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:457) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:617) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at whispereq.saver.onCommand(saver.java:14) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        ... 13 more
```

My code from the `saver` class:

```
package whispereq;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.GameMode;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class saver implements CommandExecutor {
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("config")) {
            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                if (args.length == 1) {
                    if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("set")) {
                        sender.sendMessage("§6Registering player§c " + args[0] + "§6 to Server....");
                        Player p = (Player) sender;
                        String nick = p.getName().toLowerCase();
                        String uid = p.getUniqueId().toString();
                        boolean op = p.isOp();
                        GameMode gm = p.getGameMode();
                        GameMode dgm = Bukkit.getDefaultGameMode();
                        float exp = p.getExp();
                        float explvl = p.getExpToLevel();
                        Main.getInst().getConfig().set("players." + nick + ".uuid", uid);
                        Main.getInst().getConfig().set("players." + nick + ".isOpped", op);
                        Main.getInst().getConfig().set("players." + nick + ".CurrentGameMode", gm);
                        Main.getInst().getConfig().set("players." + nick + ".DefaultGameMode", dgm);
                        Main.getInst().getConfig().set("players." + nick + ".Exp", exp);
                        Main.getInst().getConfig().set("players." + nick + ".ExpLevel", explvl);
                        Main.getInst().saveConfig();
                        sender.sendMessage("§6Finished!, yours Current in-game Status was SUccesfully registered to the config.yml File in Plugin's Directory. use  §c/registy getMe§6 to view your Property.");
                        return true;
                    } else if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("get")) {
                        Player p = (Player) sender;
                        String nick = p.getName().toLowerCase();
                        if (Main.getInst().getConfig().get("players." + nick) != null) {
                            p.sendMessage("§8_____________________________________________________");
                            p.sendMessage(Main.getInst().getConfig().getString("players." + nick + ".uuid"));
                            p.sendMessage(Main.getInst().getConfig().getString("players." + nick + ".isOpped"));
                            p.sendMessage(Main.getInst().getConfig().getString("players." + nick + ".CurrentGameMode"));
                            p.sendMessage(Main.getInst().getConfig().getString("players." + nick + ".DefaultGameMode"));
                            p.sendMessage(Main.getInst().getConfig().getString("players." + nick + ".Exp"));
                            p.sendMessage(Main.getInst().getConfig().getString("players." + nick + "ExpLevel"));
                            p.sendMessage("§8_____________________________________________________");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`Main` class:

```
package whispereq;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    public static Main instance;

    public void onEnable() {
        instance = this;
        System.out.println("Loading RegistyPlayer ..");
        getCommand("config").setExecutor(new saver());
        saveDefaultConfig();
    }

    public static Main getInst() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Config File (empty):

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------#
```

plugin.yml:

```
name: registyPlayer
version: 1.0
main: whispereq.Main
commands:
  config:
```

Craftbukkit: 1.7.2 R03

Bukkit API: 1.7.2 R03

Server Craftbukkit: 1.7.2 R03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays always start at index 0. Therefore, to access whether the player specified "get" or "set" you should replace

```
args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("set")
args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("get")
```

with

```
args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("set")
args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("get")
```

Also, not sure what you are doing with the line

```
 sender.sendMessage("§6Registering player§c " + args[0] + "§6 to Server....");
```

args[0] refers to either "get" or "set". Presumably, you should replace it with "nick" and insert the line after

```
String nick = p.getName().toLowerCase();
```